# How to commit some files on a branch and some others files to another branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow

**Scenario:**
I have 2 existing branches:

- feature/A
- feature/B

I'm on `feature/A` branch and made some changes to 5 different files.
Not all those 5 files are related to the feature A, but very often when you change/develop/fix something you find other bugs or need to change things on file which is not strictly related with the feature you are coding in that moment.

So, suppose that:

- 3 files are related to feature A
- 2 files are extra changes and related to B

When I perform local commit (I'm using Tortoise but I suppose it's similar with other softwares) I can choose which file to commit, so suppose I commit the 3 files related to A on current branch `feature/A`, leeaving the remaining 2 files changed but not committed.

Now, the two other files should be commited on `feature/B` branch but obviouvsly I cannot switch branch while some changes are not commited.

Trivial solution may be copying files as backup, revert them, switch to `feature/B` then copy backuped files and commit.

Is there a more elegant solution to problems like this one?
I know it's quite bad practice, but sometimes it could happens.

Comment: `git stash`, `git checkout`, `git stash pop` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 git add file1A file2A file3A # add the changes for feature A
 git commit -m "feature A" # on branch A
 git stash # temporarily put your changes aside
 git checkout feature/B
 git stash pop # apply the changes that you put aside again.
 git commit -am "feature B"
```

for more advanced splitting into multiple commits, I recommend you take a look at `git add -p` which allows you to split your commits per patch and not per file

Comment: I'd say that the stashing is not completely necessary since unstaged changes do not belong to a branch and will be there after a checkout.

That said, it the destination branch files are different from the files changed but not staged, the checkout is not going to happen, that's why Chris' solution is the safest and always work.

Comment: Yes, indeed, If the files are not tracked, switching to feature/B does not cause any problem, but since the OP stated that he cannot just switch, I presupposed that he was talking about changes in 5 tracked files...

Answer (score 1):

> Now, the two other files should be committed on feature/B branch but obviously I cannot switch branch while some changes are not committed.

But you can.  With any luck at all there won't be changes to files touched by your feature/A work on the B branch, and your sequence is

```
git checkout feature/B
git commit -- bfile1 bfile2
git checkout @{-1}       # @{-1} is "what I had checked out before",
                         # a.k.a. feature/A here. There's also @{-2}...
```

Drop-shipping work this way to the branches it should be recorded on is one of Git's best features.

If both branches do change some files, Git's got tools to help wrangle that too.  Easiest is often to just temporarily commit those files and reset them on the way back, but once you get familiar with the heavy artillery, aka

```
git checkout -m feature/B
```

you might not need the temporary-commit three-step. `git checkout -m` does a content merge with HEAD as the base and feature/B as the new tip.  If there aren't any conflicts at the hunk level you can then do the `git commit -- bfile1 bfile2` to drop-ship the changes you want as before, if there are you'll have to resolve them, but no matter what you can always use three of Git's best-kept secrets:

```
git add -p         # `-p` is aka `--patch`, get comfy with using this
git reset -p       # option and you'll be using the shortcut gladly
git checkout -p    # ...
```

to selectively apply hunks from (add) your worktree to the index, (reset) `HEAD` aka `@` or a named commit to the index, (checkout) the index to your worktree or a named commit to the index and worktree.

and then once you've got the index entries you want to commit on this branch looking the way you want, `git commit -- bfile1 bfile2` as usual to commit just those, `git checkout -m @{-1}` and any `-p`atchwork to fixup leftovers and orts.

Put some time into experimenting with how these work, perhaps how easy the the drop-shipping ritual is for trivial cases will suck you in, and many, many of git's less widely-used options will start to make sense.  It's been years for me now, and I'm still learning things that make me like Git more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use version control of git to do the same. Go to version control in your IDE, there you can select specific files and commit and push to the branch("A") on which you are currently. After this you can checkout your other branch "B", and then do the same procedure of selecting and committing the files you want to this branch.